# Мозаика на HTML, CSS

Tags: html, css

Запарился придумывать, пока что не придумал ни одного нормального способа мозаики , с активным элементом. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Может быть знатоки подскажут как запилить мозаику с переключающимися табами? (активный элемент слегка подсвечивается см. скрин)

Comment: Смотрите в сторону SVG масок